# C# Console Snake Tail won't be Removed

Tags: c#

I needed to program a snake game in a C# console application. I have a snake that can move, but the only problem is that it's tail won't cut, which means you can basiclly keep growing on every step done without eating a single block. I'll be happy if you could help me with that. Here's the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
 class Program
 {
    static void MainMenu() 
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(40, 12);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Write("S");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write("N");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("A");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.Write("K");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("E");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(32, 13);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to start!");
    }
    static void SnakeMovement()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
        int foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        int snakeX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
        int snakeY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        if ((snakeX == foodX) && (snakeY == foodY))
        {
            snakeX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
            snakeY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
        }
        int i = 0;
        int userScore = 0;
        ConsoleKeyInfo userAction;
        int[] ArrSnakeItselfX = new int[2000];
        int[] ArrSnakeItselfY = new int[2000];
        ArrSnakeItselfX[1] = (snakeX);
        ArrSnakeItselfY[1] = (snakeY);
        ArrSnakeItselfX[2] = (snakeX);
        ArrSnakeItselfY[2] = (snakeY - 1);
        ArrSnakeItselfX[3] = (snakeX);
        ArrSnakeItselfY[3] = (snakeY - 2);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.Write("#");
        Console.ResetColor();
        i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
            Console.Write("@");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[1], ArrSnakeItselfY[1]);
            Console.Write("$");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[2], ArrSnakeItselfY[2]);
            Console.Write("$");
            if ((snakeX == foodX) && (snakeY == foodY))
            {
                foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
                foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("#");
                Console.ResetColor();
                i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
                userScore++;
            }
            userAction = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (userAction.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ArrSnakeItselfY[0]--;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("@");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0] + 1);
                    Console.Write("$");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    if ((ArrSnakeItselfX[0] == foodX) && (ArrSnakeItselfY[0] == foodY))
                    {
                        foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
                        foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write("#");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        ArrSnakeItselfX[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1]);
                        ArrSnakeItselfY[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1] + 1);
                        i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                        userScore++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (userAction.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ArrSnakeItselfX[0] = ArrSnakeItselfX[0] + 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("@");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0] - 1, ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("$");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                    Console.Write("");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    if ((ArrSnakeItselfX[0] == foodX) && (ArrSnakeItselfY[0] == foodY))
                    {
                        foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
                        foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write("#");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        ArrSnakeItselfX[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1]);
                        ArrSnakeItselfY[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1] + 1);
                        i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                        userScore++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (userAction.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ArrSnakeItselfX[0] = ArrSnakeItselfX[0] - 1;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("@");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0] + 1, ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("$");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                    Console.Write("");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    if ((ArrSnakeItselfX[0] == foodX) && (ArrSnakeItselfY[0] == foodY))
                    {
                        foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
                        foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write("#");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        ArrSnakeItselfX[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1]);
                        ArrSnakeItselfY[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1] + 1);
                        i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                        userScore++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (userAction.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ArrSnakeItselfY[0]++;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
                    Console.Write("@");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0] - 1);
                    Console.Write("$");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                    Console.Write("");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    if ((ArrSnakeItselfX[0] == foodX) && (ArrSnakeItselfY[0] == foodY))
                    {
                        foodX = rnd.Next(1, 80);
                        foodY = rnd.Next(1, 25);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodX, foodY);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write("#");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        ArrSnakeItselfX[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1]);
                        ArrSnakeItselfY[i] = (ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1] + 1);
                        i = ArrSnakeItselfX.Count();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
                        userScore++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }      
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            ConsoleKeyInfo userStartingGame;
            MainMenu();
            userStartingGame = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (userStartingGame.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                SnakeMovement();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't update the coordinates of any `ArrSnakeItSelfX` except `ArrSnakeItSelfX[0]` which is the head of the snake while moving without eating. All other coordinates in the array are wrong, so

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[i - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[i - 1]);
Console.Write(" ");
```

Always writes to the same screen position.

While your snake moves without eating, you must shift all you coordinates in the arrays by one to the back. So the last position (the old tail) gets erased, and insert the new head position at index 0 in the array.

```
var e = ArrSnakeItselfX.Length;

Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[e - 1], ArrSnakeItselfY[e - 1]);
Console.Write(" ");  //erase tail of snake

for (int i = e-1; i>0; i--) { //shift all coordinates by one position in the array
   ArrSnakeItselfX[i] = ArrSnakeItselfX[i-1];
   ArrSnakeItselfY[i] = ArrSnakeItselfY[i-1];
}

//set new head position
ArrSnakeItselfX[0] = //new x of head;
ArrSnakeItselfY[0] = //new y of head;
Console.SetCursorPosition(ArrSnakeItselfX[0], ArrSnakeItselfY[0]);
Console.Write("@");
```

When you eat something, you basically have to do the same thing, except, you don't drop the last element, but increase the arraysize by one and keep the last element.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still need to enhance the code, but I'm nearly done now!

Comment: For instance instead of using two arrays you could use a `List<Point>` because a point can hold both coordinates and with a list you can just remove the last element and insert a new one in the front, so you won't have to copy all elements for shifting positions

Comment: I do know that, however this is a project for school and the instructions are to use arrays.